# Getting error on flutter project on creating build in Xcode ( iOS ) - error: unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios10.0'

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, flutter-razorpay

Hi I am getting this error on build iOS Xcode.

error: unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios10.0'

Module compiled with Swift 5.5.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.6 compiler: /Users/macmini/StudioProjects/customer-app-flutter-2.10.2/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

Comment: I would try building this on Xcode 13.2 instead of Xcode 13.3 if you're using the latest